# SQL CASE address type

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to pull a single address from the database where there is a possibility of multiple addresses based on an Addresstype. Will the following return the Main address only, even if there is also a mailing address? I want one or the other but not both.

```
SELECT accountnumber,
       addressline1,
       addressline2,
       addressline3,
       city,
       stateorprov,
       zippostalcode
FROM   andar.addresses
WHERE  addresstype =
          (CASE WHEN addresstype = 'Main' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Mailing' END)
```

Comment: Your question is wrong. You *should* have inserted two records, ran your query and observed that the answer to your question is "No". When you are stuck fixing that problem, you could have asked for help here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the expected result? Also, What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `case` in the `where` clause is typically a bad idea. I would strongly encourage you to re-write this using Boolean logic.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I want to get the Main address if it exists, if it doesn't exist, I want to get the Mailing address but only one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is `No`. It will return `Mailing`.

If `addresstype = 'Main'` then `(CASE WHEN addresstype = 'Main' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Mailing' END)` evaluates to `Main` and thus predicate is `True`.

If `addresstype = 'Mailing'` then `(CASE WHEN addresstype = 'Main' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Mailing' END)` evaluates to `Mailing` and thus predicate is `True` again.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't work the way you want .. but you can try something like this:

```
  select * from (
     SELECT accountnumber,
            addressline1,
            addressline2,
            addressline3,
            city,
            stateorprov,
            zippostalcode,
            row_number() over (partition by accountnumber
                           order by case when addresstype = 'Main' then 0 else 1 end  rnum
     FROM   andar.addresses
     )
  where rnum = 1
  /
```